# Using Bootstrap how do I layout elements horizontally?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below  that I am trying to replicate this mock-up --> [image: DoorPanelImage]

I am stuck on how to make my elements display horizontally?  Would I need to make a list or another "table"?  Was able to accomplish it using `style` but it seems like I shouldn't need to.

Here's what I have so far -->

```
<div id="Row1" class="row">
<div id="Door1" class="col-md-2 panel panel-primary" >
    <div id="Door1Head" class="panel-heading">
        <span class="badge">1</span>
        <h3 class="panel-title">RE031159</h3>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                12315 Carregeenan WG-16 4000 lbs
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                1063545 Carp meal spread 1042 lbs
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Door2" class="col-md-2">
    <span class="badge">2</span>
</div>
<div id="Door3" class="col-md-2">
    <span class="badge">3</span>
</div>
<div id="Door4" class="col-md-2">
    <span class="badge">4</span>
</div>
<div id="Door5" class="col-md-2">
    <span class="badge">5</span>
</div>
```

```
<div id="Row2" class="row">
    <div id="Door6" class="col-md-2">
        <span class="badge">6</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Door7" class="col-md-2">
        <span class="badge">7</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Door8" class="col-md-2">
        <span class="badge">8</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Door9" class="col-md-2">
        <span class="badge">9</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Door10" class="col-md-2">
        <span class="badge">10</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For bigger picture, I am using Bootstrap 3 within an MVC 5 app.  I will be populating the info in the mock-up from a SQL DB using EF6.  I am imagining that I will be using some `@foreach` loops to build each "card".

Comment: Note: each `div` with class `row` has to have columns adding up to 12. Your `col-lg-2` only add up to 10

Comment: I actually changed to `col-md-2`, does that change anything?

Comment: It will still need to add up to 12, per row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in a bunch of other comments, all your columns in a row need to add up to 12. There is a couple of ways to correct this. The answer proposed by Robb puts an empty column on each end of the row in order to do this. You could also limit 4 "doors" per row and increase the size of each column to 3. Finally you could come up with a 10 column system, but that might be a little extreme given then other two solutions.

As far as your headers not aligning horizontally. The following code [demos](http://jsfiddle.net/NYvA8/2/) one possible way to do it.

My changes are

```
    <div id="Door1Head" class="panel-heading">
      <span class="badge pull-left">1</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up pull-right" ></span>
      <h3 class="panel-title text-center">RE031159</h3>
      <div class="clearfix text-center">Some text here</div>
    </div>
```

Maybe not the best way to do things in bootstrap, but it works. Hopefully someone can build off of this to get you what you are looking for.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for.  2 questions.... 1st: for me the `<h3>` is still not displaying centered.  It's touching the "1".  2nd: What does the `clearfix` do?

Comment: Clearfix just resets the float for that element. I would encourage you to check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix  . To center the text just add the class .text-center . I have updated my answer

Comment: This is what I needed.  Thanks!  Now to integrate dynamicness into it.  Hopefully I won't need to have a follow up SO post on swapping `class` based on my `@model`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but I'd work at having a single row and getting my panels to just iterate inside the row. Something like this:

```
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-2 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span class="badge">01</span>
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Title</h3>
    </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
  </div><!--/span-->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

[Working Bootply example with responsive panels](http://bootply.com/93946)

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Still trying to figure out how to get my item's in the "header" to display horizontally.

Comment: You could add .pull-left to the badge and .pull-right to the panel-title. The styling around the heading block needs a little more work, but I updated the Bootply sample to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a completely out-of-the-box solution, I'd recommend using 4 doors per row with a `col-lg-3` so that you can easily match the 12 column grid layout that is inherit in Bootstrap.  Otherwise, you'll have to add some custom CSS to enable a 10-column layout.

You pretty much have the concept of how to make horizontal rows already - just make a `div` with a class of `row` followed by more `div` elements with their size measurements summing up to 12.

I've made a quick update of your fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pjvzc/2/) which basically just fixes some of the HTML you had originally and converted them to `col-lg-3`.

If you want more precise measurements within the grid, make sure you look up `col-xs`, `col-sm`, and `col-md` at their [**website**](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

In order to do this more dynamically, just keep an ongoing counter; every time you hit 4, you reset the counter and you generate a new row and fill elements in.

Comment: When you say there size measuring up to 12.  Do you mean the number portion of `col-md-2`?  I need those to add up to 12?

Answer (score 1):

For a static solution

```
<!-- ROW 1 -->
    <div id="Row1" class="row">
        <div id="row1SideBarL" class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div id="Door1" class="col-lg-2 panel panel-primary" >
            <div id="Door1Head" class="panel-heading">
                <span class="badge">1</span>
                <h3 class="panel-title">RE031159</h3>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        12315 Carregeenan WG-16 4000 lbs
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        1063545 Carp meal spread 1042 lbs
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Door2" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">2</span>
        </div>
        <div id="Door3" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">3</span>
        </div>
        <div id="Door4" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">4</span>
        </div>
        <div id="Door5" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">5</span>
        </div>
        <div id="row1SideBarR" class="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>

<!-- ROW 2 -->
    <div id="Row2" class="row">
        <div id="row2SideBarL" class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div id="Door6" class="col-lg-2 panel panel-primary" >
        </div>    
        <div id="Door7" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">2</span>
        </div>
        <div id="Door8" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">3</span>
        </div>
        <div id="Door9" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">4</span>
        </div>
        <div id="Door10" class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="badge">5</span>
        </div>
        <div id="row2SideBarR" class="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but this doesn't seem to solve my issue of getting elements, specifically the "1", "RE031159","Up Arrow" to display horizontally.  What does the "SideBar" div's do for me?

Comment: Sidebar divs just get you to so that all the columns in the row add up to 12.

Answer (score 0):

the col-lg- should be in total 12 for every row

you can find this and many other informations at the docu: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

besides this you can also realize something like this without bootstrap by few css lines:

```
width:20%
height:250px;
display:block;
float:left;
```

Comment: sry the ölink is for the bootstrap 2 version, but different are just the css classes here latest: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid